# Stuck on integrating $\int x/(1-x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

My attempt:

Let $u = 1-x$ , $du = -dx$ , $x = 1-u$, so: 
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{x}{1-x}\, dx &= - \int \frac{1-u}u\, du \\
&= - \left( \int \frac 1 u\, du - \int 1 \, du \right) \\
&= - \ln(|u|) + u \\
 &= -\ln(|1-x|) + (1-x)
\end{align*}

But the answer is supposed to be $-x - \ln(|1-x|)$. Why do I have an extra 1?

Comment: You forgot the arbitrary constant. The constant in your answer is simply off by $1$ compared to the book's constant. Your answers are equivalent.

Comment: Wow I feel pretty stupid right now. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ln|x|+C$.

Comment: Noted. Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indefinite integrals always have an extra constant term. The general answer is $-x - \ln|1-x| + C$. If you add a constant term to both your answer and the one you said it is supposed to be, you will find that they are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\displaylines{
  \int {\frac{x}{{1 - x}}dx}  = \int {\frac{{x + 1 - 1}}{{1 - x}}dx}  \cr 
   = \int {\left( { - 1 + \frac{1}{{1 - x}}} \right)dx}  \cr 
   =  - x - \ln \left| {1 - x} \right| + c \cr}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also simplify it by using long division and then integrate.
e.g $\frac{x}{1-x}=-1+\frac{1}{1-x} $ which integrates to $-x-\ln|1-x|+c$.